# Google CloudSQL for PostgreSQL HA cluster downtime due to maintenance without failover

Tags: google-cloud-sql

This morning we experienced a downtime of a little over 5 minutes on our Google CloudSQL for PostgreSQL High Available (HA) cluster. This was during the maintenance period that Google requires you to provide.

Google is clear on why they need the maintenance window (see [here](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/instance-settings#maintenance-window-2ndgen)). What struck us was the duration of the downtime and that no failover was performed.

The documentation is clear on that the maintenance is performed on an instance (and not on the cluster as a whole). So why was the fallback not performed like is documented [here](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/high-availability#failover-overview)? It could take up to 60 seconds, they say. But it took a little over 5 minutes.

And then again; it is a scheduled maintenance. Automated failover should not have to take place if you anticipate.

Did we misinterpret the documentation, do we have unrealistic expectations or did we misconfigure our application?

Answer (score 0):

As described in the document that you are referring, it's intended only for the event of an instance or zone failure. In other words, only if the instance fails (become unresponsive) or if there is an issue in the zone where the MySQL/PostgreSQL instance is located that causes that the instance cannot be reached, then Cloud SQL will automatically switch to serving data from the standby instance.

Also, in the same document is indicated that the primary instance must be in a normal operating state, this is mentioned in the [requirements](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/high-availability#failover-requirements) section.

Comment: Thanks Alan for your answer. That seems to be a plausible explanation why it was not using failover. It just doesn't seem to be right that a High Availability solution can experience a downtime of over 5 minutes during scheduled maintenance. Do other people have similar experiences?

Comment: Yes, as per indicated in the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/instance-settings#maintenance-window-2ndgen), the expected downtime is just a couple of minutes, but if the downtime takes more than 10 mins I would recommend that you contact the support team to review the instance and assist you in case there's an issue with the maintenance.

Comment: The implications of "a couple of minutes" downtime are potentially huge. Why does Google need downtime for _scheduled_ maintenance on a HA product? It strikes me as a flaw in their design if it's really the case. I didn't experience this with the HA version of Amazon RDS while using this service for over a year.

Comment: I understand that downtime due to maintenance may not be ideal behavior on a HA instance, but that is the purpose of the maintenance window, mitigate the impact on your system due to the downtime. However, Google is always looking to improve their products, I found a couple of feature requests to allow an automatic trigger of the failover on an instance that has HA, there is not an ETA of when this feature will be implemented.

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/111521234 
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/111429144

Comment: Thanks for sharing those links! Glad to find out that there are others that encourage this improvement